# nullpointerexception when starting apache flume

Tags: apache, hadoop, nullpointerexception, flume

I am trying to run flume and I am getting nullpointerexception:

---

> .jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/training/Downloads/hive-0.10.0/lib/*'
>   -Djava.library.path=:/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../lib/native/Linux-i386-32
>   org.apache.flume.node.Application --name agent SLF4J: Class path
>   contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/training/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/home/training/Downloads/hive-0.10.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. 15/10/13 05:47:28 ERROR node.Application: A fatal error
>   occurred while running. Exception follows.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.File.(File.java:251)
>   at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:302)
>
> ---

The command I used to start flume is as follows:

flume:

> ./flume-ng agent --conf
>   /home/training/Downloads/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/conf/flume-conf.properties.template
>   --name agent
>
> The flume config file is as follows:
>
> agent.sources=seqGenSrc agent.channels=memoryChannel
>   agent.sinks=loggerSink
>
> agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type=exec agent.sources.seqGenSrc.command=tail
>   -F /home/training/Desktop/log.txt agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels=memoryChannel
>   agent.sinks.loggerSink.type=logger
>   agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel=memoryChannel
>   agent.channels.memoryChannel.type=memory
>   agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=100
>
> agent.sinks.loggerSink.type=hdfs
>   agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:54310/user/training/logs
>   agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.fileType=DataStream

Could you please let me know what I am missing.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I notice:

1. In your command you use the `--conf` argument, but you omit the `--conf-file` argument. For example, I start flume like this:

`./bin/flume-ng agent -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console --conf ./conf --conf-file ./conf/test.conf --name agent`

2. In your config you first set the type of the sink to `loggerSink` and then you set the type of the sink to `hdfs`. I don't think setting the type of the sink twice is what you want (or what Flume wants).

btw, I reformatted your config:

```
agent.sources=seqGenSrc
agent.channels=memoryChannel
agent.sinks=loggerSink

agent.sources.seqGenSrc.type=exec
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.command=tail -F /home/training/Desktop/log.txt
agent.sources.seqGenSrc.channels=memoryChannel
agent.sinks.loggerSink.type=logger
agent.sinks.loggerSink.channel=memoryChannel
agent.channels.memoryChannel.type=memory
agent.channels.memoryChannel.capacity=100

agent.sinks.loggerSink.type=hdfs
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.path=hdfs://localhost:54310/user/training/logs
agent.sinks.loggerSink.hdfs.fileType=DataStream
```